# Node API - Getting rate limit when looping through results

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with Node to pull data from an API. In order to get through the API (it's paginated to 10 results per page), I'm using a for loop. I keep getting the error "Rate limit exceeded", but I'm not sure why. I've added a timeout but that hasn't changed it. My code is below:

```
const https = require('https');
var i = 1; 

for (i = 0; i <= 50; i=i+10) {
  setDelay(i);
}

var url = encodeURIComponent('https://www.google.com/search?q=%22founder%22+%22stealth%22+site:linkedin.com&lr=&as_qdr=all&sxsrf=ALeKk02QyRlLxFA21sGpXKvkeM-cpsBMpQ:1590868596522&ei=dLrSXpKuH8ToxgPr3bPgCg&start=' + i + '&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiSuNGsr9zpAhVEtHEKHevuDKwQ8tMDegQIDBAt&biw=1536&bih=726');

const options = {
    hostname: 'api.proxycrawl.com',
    path: '/scraper?token={TOKEN}&url=' + url
};


function setDelay(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    https.request(options, (response) => {
      let body = '';
      response.on('data', chunk => body += chunk).on('end', () => console.log(body));
      }).end();
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the node API?

Comment: you're making too many API requests in too short a time. where is the timeout you say you added?

Comment: @DanO I just edited my code with the day that I added. I still get the same timeout, can you suggest why?